# Teenagers on a spaceship that was sentient/had AI, waking up at different times from sarcophagus-like bed

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, spaceship

I remember reading in the late 80's / early 90's a trilogy (I think) about some teens in a spaceship that was sentient / had AI, and they weren't allowed in one section of the spaceship because it was dangerous.

Some of the teens came awake at different times, and were in a sarcophagus like bed for a while, and when they were in there, they were back on Earth or something?

There was something in the other part of the spaceship that wanted to attack them, and part of me thinks that they were shadow-type creatures.

Argh, it's annoying me that the memories are so vague and that I can't remember, I loved the trilogy as a kid!

Comment: Ok - so of course after posting this, I find the answer (thanks to my older brother who I remembered introduced me to the series). 

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_trilogy - a bit of an obscure series by a NZ author. Just in case anyone comes across this and wants to know!

Comment: You can add that as an answer to your own question, and accept it, too

Comment: There is a delay before you may accept a self-answer. Could be 72 hours if my memory doesn't fail me.

Answer (score 5):

As per the querent's comment, this is apparently the [Deepwater trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_trilogy).

Comment: Adding this just in case he doesn't come back so that this story shows up as having an answer.